# What are the options for transferring 60GB+ files over the a network?

Tags: networking, ftp, network-programming, compression

I'm about to start developing an application to transfer very large files without any rush but with need of reliability. I would like people that had worked coding such a particular case give me an insight of what I'm about to get into.

The environment will be intranet  ftp server> so far using active ftp normal ports windows systems. I might need to also zip up the files before sending and I remember working with a library once that would zip in memory and there was a limit on the size... ideas on this would also be appreciated.

Let me know if I need to clarify something else. I'm asking for general/higher level gotchas if any not really detail help. I've done apps with normal sizes (up to 1GB) before but this one seems I'd need to limit the speed so I don't kill the network or things like that.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get some inspiration from torrents.

Torrents generally break up the file in manageable pieces and calculate a hash of them. Later they transfer them piece by piece. Each piece is verified against hashes and accepted only if matched. This is very effective mechanism and let the transfer happen from multiple sources and also let is restart any number of time without worrying about corrupted data.

For transfer from a server to single client, I would suggest that you create a header which includes the metadata about the file so the receiver always knows what to expect and also knows how much has been received and can also check the received data against hashes.

I have practically implemented this idea on a client server application but the data size was much smaller, say 1500k but reliability and redundancy were important factors. This way, you can also effectively control the amount of traffic you want to allow through your application.

Comment: Good idea too. Where did you learn how torrents work? Do you have any meaningful link? or perhaps a book that I can purchase to investigate further?

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to go is to use the rsync utility as an external process to Python -

Quoting from [here](http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/data-services/transport/rsync):

> the pieces, using checksums, to possibly existing files in the target
>   site, and transports only those pieces that are not found from the
>   target site. In practice this means that if an older or partial
>   version of a file to be copied already exists in the target site,
>   rsync transports only the missing parts of the file. In many cases
>   this makes the data update process much faster as all the files are
>   not copied each time the source and target site get synchronized.

And you can use the -z switch to have compression on the fly for the data transfer transparently, no need to boottle up either end compressing the whole file.

Also, check the answers here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/154254/for-large-files-compress-first-then-transfer-or-rsync-z-which-would-be-fastest

And from rsync's man page, this might be of interest:

> ```
>    --partial
>           By  default,  rsync  will  delete any partially transferred
>           file if the transfer is interrupted. In some  circumstances
>           it  is  more desirable to keep partially transferred files.
>           Using the --partial option tells rsync to keep the  partial
>           file which should make a subsequent transfer of the rest of
>           the file much faster
> ```

Comment: Great idea!! it wasn't even in my head!